# windows for trivial app?

Tags: windows, linux, development-environment

we have a small app that doing trivial stuff, no GUI.

we was using Linux, but the library/framework available for Linux is highly less than that for windows,  it was such a pain to develop under Linux.

So we want to use windows, but windows is too big for the trivial app, is there any solution that i can use windows and not losing OS's lightweight?

any advices appreciated.

Comment: is XP Embedded suit your need?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of applications are you building?

1) some older versions of windows have less bloat, but you wouldn't want these running on public networks because they don't get security updates. Plus, the latest/greatest libraries may not run on them

2) If you're running command-line server utilities, you could try Windows 2008 Server Core, which is a console-only installation

3) You might want to try Wine or Mono to run your windows/.NET framework-based application.

Answer (score 1):

You should try a "Windows PE" (sometimes also called "minint") installation ([installation guide here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883390/EN-US/)), which is a trimmed-down version based on Windows XP or Vista.

Answer (score 1):

This does not make sense, sorry. If you have a CLI program under Linux why shouldn't you be able to write on CLI program on Windows?